# create lattice in tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to make a grid/lattice of particles on my tinter canvas. I would then like these particles to move using the canvas.move function reading the coordinates from a text file. I tried to make the lattice in a loop.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
import time
import csv


tk = Tk()
N = 100
T = 500
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=100, height=100)
tk.title("Test")
canvas.pack()
n = 5
t = 10

step1 = []
step2 = []
textFile1 = open('/Users/francislempp/Desktop/major project/C++        programs/Molecular Dynamics 2D/Molecular_Dynamics_2D-   gupnvjunowwmjcfiyoursdhzytow/Build/Products/Debug/motionX', 'r')
lines = textFile1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    step1.append(line.split(" "))

textFile2 = open('/Users/francislempp/Desktop/major project/C++ programs/Molecular Dynamics 2D/Molecular_Dynamics_2D-gupnvjunowwmjcfiyoursdhzytow/Build/Products/Debug/motionY', 'r')
lines = textFile2.readlines()
for line in lines:
    step2.append(line.split(" "))


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color, size, x, y):
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(10,10,size,size, fill = color)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def move(self):
        canvas.move(self.shape, self.x, self.y)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[3] >= 100 or pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = -self.y
        if pos[2] > 100 or pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = -self.x

    def delete(self):
        canvas.delete(self.shape)


balls = []



for i in range(99):
    for j in range(99):
        xcoord = i*(100/10) + 4
        ycoord = j*(100/10) + 4
        canvas.create_oval(xcoord,ycoord,2,2, fill = "red")
tk.update()



tk.mainloop()
```

when i run my code it make ovals which run down the screen and overlap each other. I would like the for loop to place 100 particles inside the canvas with equal spacing.

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Have you examined `xcoord` and `ycoord` to see if they are what you think they should be? Also, there's a lot of unused code in your question -- you never use the `Ball` class, why is it there?

Comment: remove unused elements like `random`, `time`, `csv`, `Ball`, `balls`, `step1`, `step2`, etc.

Comment: btw: you can use `10` instead of `100/10`

Comment: the ball class is there because later i would like to move each ball according to a list of coordinates that i import from a text file generated in another c++ program. Hence the definition of the move function in the class and the creation of step1 and step2 arrays referring to the x and y coords respectively

Comment: as far as  debugging i am quite new to tkinter and so i am not sure where to start with that

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `(x, y, x+1, y+1)` or even `(x, y, x, y)` to create small dots with the same size.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.pack()

for i in range(10):
    x = i*10 + 4
    for j in range(10):
        y = j*10 + 4
        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x, y, fill="red")
        #canvas.create_oval((x, y, x, y), fill="red") # or with `()`

root.mainloop()
```

or using all parameters in `range()`

```
for x in range(4, 100, 10):
    for y in range(4, 100, 10):
        canvas.create_oval((x, y, x, y), fill="red")
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** to move (randomly) all points in the same direction

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def move():
    x = random.randint(-1, 1)
    y = random.randint(-1, 1)
    for point_id in points:
        canvas.move(point_id, x, y)
    root.after(100, move)

# --- main ---

points = []

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
canvas.pack()

for i in range(10):
    x = i*10 + 4
    for j in range(10):
        y = j*10 + 4
        point_id = canvas.create_oval(x, y, x, y, fill="red")
        points.append(point_id)
        #canvas.create_oval((x, y, x, y), fill="red") # or with `()`

move()
root.mainloop()
```

Or to move every pixel in different direction

```
def move():
    for point_id in points:
        x = random.randint(-1, 1)
        y = random.randint(-1, 1)
        canvas.move(point_id, x, y)
    root.after(100, move)
```

Comment: thanks alot, i have got a lattice. but now i move like each element of the lattice to move according to a list of coords a provide from a text file (from the arrays step1 and step2). I tried using canvas.move by defining a function but it won't update the points

Comment: `point_id = canvas.create_oval()` gives ID for every point which you have to keep on list and use with `move(point_id, ...)`

Comment: see new example in answer